# Capacitor charge offset (pre-charge)

Tags: led, capacitor, mosfet, strip

I use capacitor (on Gate) to open MOSFET slowly to fade in/out LED strip. It works fine except some delay before light starts to show. I understand that it is because led strip didn’t receive enough power while mosfet opens.

I like the slow fade in which I have, but I want to get rid of that delay.

Comment: Please read https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question.

Comment: This is not a good way to fade LEDs.... You should look into PWM dimming instead of doing it linearly like you are.

Comment: @MadHatter thank you for your advice.

Comment: @Dampmaskin in oh, sorry. I’ll read it.